# Swig-template delete Whitespaces per default

Tags: swig-template

I am using Swig as the template engine in my project to create XML.
To make the XML output look nice I need to add a "`-`" everytime I use the template functions (`{% -%}, {{ -}}, {# -#}`).

It would be nice to be able to change the default behavior to always strip whitespace before and after. Is there a setting for this already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't.

The stripping is done in line 624 in `parser.js`:
https://github.com/paularmstrong/swig/blob/2e0e135ac04da5bf75f79cf8d4498094b3b49d35/lib/parser.js#L624

The variables `stripNext` and `stripPrev` are set to true only if a tag or a variable expression includes this `-`. If not stripping will not be done. There is no other way.

Comment: That is very true. Let's see if we can change that